# I want to see what processes do most of disk writes in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, osx-mountain-lion, top

I run Mac OS X 10.8.2 and I want to find out what processes do most of disk writes. Ideally, I would like to see a complete report for a period of say 10 hours, with sorted data showing top performers.

I know that essentially in Linux something as simple as running iotop -o -a can give me something like this:
[image]

Any ideas/solutions for Mac OS X?

Comment: OS X has `iotop` as well, though probably not the exact same. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Sure, there's no -a or anything like that. It would seem most Mac OS X console apps can show fewer information compared to Linux. Anyway, I don't care if it's done with iotop or not, I need to get this data :)